# CRM SDK update record with related lookup

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an entity (Server) which has a 1:N lookup field on another entity (Host).
From the SDK I can easily create records:

```
foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vmObjects)
        {
            new_server newServer = new new_server();
            newServer.new_name = vm.Name;
            newServer.new_Memory = vm.Memory;
            newServer.new_new_host_new_server_Host = xrm.new_hostSet.Where(x => x.new_HostSCVMMId == vm.HostId).Single();
            xrm.AddObject(newServer);
        }
        xrm.SaveChanges();
```

The new records has the correct "Host" lookup related field set.
Now, when I try to update the records:

```
foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vmObjects)
        {
            new_server updateServer = xrm.new_serverSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.new_VMId == vm.VMId);
            if (updateServer != null)
            {
                updateServer.new_name = vm.Name;
                updateServer.new_Memory = vm.Memory;
                updateServer.new_new_host_new_server_Host = xrm.new_hostSet.Where(x => x.new_HostSCVMMId == vm.HostId).Single();
                xrm.UpdateObject(updateServer);
            }
        }
        xrm.SaveChanges();
```

It gives the following error (if I comment out the line with the new_host_new_server_Host then it will update eg. memory correctly.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll
Additional information: The collection is read-only.
```

Why can't I update the Host property of the record just because it is a lookup field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set the property with the type EntityReference instead of the property you are setting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I struggle to figure out how to do it with EntityReference. Can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks BlueSam,

I finally got it:

```
Guid hostGuid = xrm.new_hostSet.Where(x => x.new_HostSCVMMId == vm.HostId).Single().Id;
                updateServer.new_Host = new Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference("new_host", hostGuid);
```